# How to make WiFi reduced transmit power level persist across reboots?

Tags: wifi, systemd-networkd, iw

**TL;DR**

I have reduced the transmit power of a WiFi device and I would like to make this change permanent, so it does not revert after a reboot.

**Details**

I have joined two Raspberry Pi 4 devices to an existing WiFi network, and I have discovered that by default they transmit at 31 dBm, which is quite high.  I was getting a lot of latency, in that it would work fine for 10 seconds and then pretty much stop for 5 seconds, then repeat.  I discovered that if I lower the transmit power on both devices to only 10 dBm then the latency dramatically improves.

I did this by running the command `iw wlan0 set txpower limit 1000`.

I would like to make this setting persistent across reboots, however I can't see anything in systemd-networkd or wpa_supplicant that controls transmit power.

Is there a way to set this (e.g. in systemd's `.network` or `.link` file for the WiFi connection)?

Failing that, what would be the best way to do this?  I am guessing a udev rule would be better than a systemd service as it would run only when the device is available however any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set your regulatory country?

Comment: Google for `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`

Comment: Yes regulatory country is correct, but I want to set the transmit power to one third of what is allowed.  It defaults to the maximum allowed but that is too high.  I Googled for that but NetworkManager seems to cover the same ground as systemd-networkd so it's probably overkill for setting one value, and I'm not even sure whether it can do that as I have no experience with it either.

Comment: Well, if you think it is overkill, you could still use a `@reboot` cron entry

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a "Startup Applications" thingamajig on your flavor of Linux, you can do:

```
sudo sh -c "iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 1000"
```

You can go all the way down to:

```
sudo sh -c "iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 0"
```

... which would be 1 mW transmit power (which would only work if you're very near your WiFi router).

Comment: Yep this is a hack that works, but there is no startup folder as these are headless devices used as IP cameras, so there is no desktop environment.  I could use systemd units but it would be nice if there was a way to include this in with the rest of the systemd-networkd config so all the network stuff is in the same place.